# Is address.send(1) an alias for address.call.value(1).gas(2300)()?

Tags: contract-development, ether

As I understand it, these two statements do exactly the same thing and they can be used interchangeable in the code. Is their bytecode identical?

- **address.send(1)**
- **address.call.value(1).gas(2300)()**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`address.send(1)` is equivalent to `address.call.value(1).gas(0)()`.  Forward 0 gas because 2300 is a default gas stipend, the last [subtlety](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Subtleties).

[Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/b2507e9f105ab701c417f8f2d125edf8f3022698/libsolidity/codegen/ExpressionCompiler.cpp#L569-L571):

```
    case Location::Send:
        _functionCall.expression().accept(*this);
        m_context << u256(0); // do not send gas (there still is the stipend)
```

[Serpent](https://github.com/ethereum/serpent/blob/a33ef614655678a422fdcfdafa0c69dd595717e6/rewriter.cpp#L153-L154):

```
    "(send $to $value)",
    "(~call 0 $to $value 0 0 0 0)"
```

Comment: I've seen **address.gas(0).value(1).call()()** used somewhere. There's additional pair of parentheses. Does this syntax changes anything? Or is it the third way of doing exactly the same thing?

Comment: `.call` must be after `address` otherwise you have a syntax error `Member "gas" not found`...

Answer (score 1):

Yep, their bytecodes are identical:

```
contract A {
    function(){
        address A = 0x0EF91f087165cfDe0b51F10D8ed69a670A1f89CB;
        A.call.value(1).gas(0)();        
    }
}
```

---

```
contract A {
    function(){
        address A = 0x0EF91f087165cfDe0b51F10D8ed69a670A1f89CB;
        A.send(1);        
    }
}
```

---

6060604052603f8060106000396000f360606040523615600a575b603d604051730ef91f087165cfde0b51f10d8ed69a670a1f89cb90819060009060019082818181858883f1505050505050565b00

---

6060604052603f8060106000396000f360606040523615600a575b603d604051730ef91f087165cfde0b51f10d8ed69a670a1f89cb90819060009060019082818181858883f1505050505050565b00